# how to change classes of html elements obtained from ng-click()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an html element as :

```
<i ng-click="run()"></i>
```

and in my controller:

```
$scope.run() = function($event) {
   var el = $event.currentTarget;
}
```

now how can i want to add some classes on the `el` element but `el.addClass('class-name')` is not working

**I can only use javascript here not jquery**

Comment: `el.classList.add('className')`. You can also use `ng-class` and have a flag that will update on click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When modifying classes on elements using the [classList API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) you need to use the classList namespace. i.e.

```
el.classList.add('class-name');
```

It looks like you are still thinking in jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

```
ng-class="expression"
```

Its recommended that you use `ng-class` instead of using controller to add class.

but you can use `element.classList.add('className')` also if you want

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<i ng-click="run($event)"></i>
```

JS:

```
$scope.run() = function(event) {
   var element = angular.element(event.currentTarget);
   element.addClass('new');
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-class here is the demo [Jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vvcg78z7/1/)

**Js code**

```
  var app = angular.module('app', []);
  app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myClass = false;
    $scope.addClass = function() {
      $scope.myClass = true;
    }
  });
```

**HTML**

```
  <div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller='ctrl'>
      <span ng-class='{myClass:myClass}'>This my content</span>

      <button ng-click='addClass()'>
        Add class
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a more propriate way to do it, is to use `ng-class` for your `i` element, and bind it to some variable on your scope.

Example:

Your HTML:

```
<i ng-click="changeClass()" ng-class="myClass"></i>
```

Your Angular controller:

```
function Controller($scope){

 $scope.myClass = "";
 $scope.changeClass = function() {
     $scope.myClass = //Put here your CSS class
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-class in Angular js

```
<i ng-class="myclass" ng-click="run()"></i>
```

in controller

```
$scope.run() = function(event) {
  $scope.myclass="classname";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add like this,in HTML

```
<i ng-click="run($event)">i</i>
```

In contoller

```
 $scope.run = function($event) {
            $event.target.classList.add("className")
        }
```